# Samba: hiding sub folder for certain users

Tags: samba, network-share

Is there any way to hide all sub folders in the shares matching pattern for one (or all but one) user?

I would like to have a sub directory (let's call it `_private_data`) which should be visible to `user1` but not to `user2`. But I cannot know where this directory will be beforehand. 
It might be that `user1` creates a directory `ShareThis/LookHere` and then creates the directory `ShareThis/LookHere/_private_data`. 'user2' Has also permission to read `ShareThis/LookHere` and all the sub directories but he should not be able to see the `_private_data` sub directory.

Is it somehow possible to do that? I already found the `hide files`, `veto files` and `dont descend` options. Which look pretty similar to what I want, but I have no idea how to assign them to some users only and how to make them match in any sub directory of the share.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a solution. It works by including a file based on the user name. You have to create (or symlink) a file for every user you want to allow browsing the _priv directory, but that's fine for me.

The following is an example for a share called 'Images'.

smb.conf:

```
[Images]
comment = Shared Images
path = /path/to/images
write list = user1, user2
valid users = user1, user2

# make sure the _priv directory cannot be accessed
hide files = /_priv/
veto files = /_priv/

# The following line allows to revert hide and veto options so that
# specific users are allowed to view private directories
include = /etc/samba/allowprivate.conf.%U
```

and then for every user that should be able to access the directories create an allowprivate.conf. (e.g. allowprivate.conf.user1) with the following content:

```
# This reverts the settings from smb.conf, so that this user
# can access all files
hide files =  
veto files =
```

It does even work on sub-directories, so 'privileged' users can just create a `_priv` directory and unprivileged users won't be able to access that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I guess as the directory should be hidden it should also not be readable for the other users.
You may want to look into the parameter `hide unreadable` that essentially hides files and directories the user is not allowed to read. You can set this on a per-share basis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have a look. But I assume this does not answer my question as my issues focus on how to apply certain options to sub folders only

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1. create users and groups
2. let only `user1` and users in `admin` group can see this folder.

```
[Images]
...
hide unreadable = yes
force user = %U
force group = +smbadmin
```

```
# /path/to/images
chmod 770 _priv
chown user1:admin _priv
```